# Fallback observer for custom eventbus with RxJava / RxAndroid?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, event-bus

I am currently researching for better ways to handle events in my app.
Currently I have multiple listeners that are subscribing and unsubscribing to interesting objects on different events.

E.g. on a button click a listener is created, that listens on a client object, if a operation succeeded (in that case it automatically unregisters itself) or if a non fatal error occurs (in that case it automatically retries the operation).

The client object in turn is starting a android service that can emit different status events, that should result in the user interface updating itself or alternatively show notifications, if the app is currently not visible.

In my app I have a really big listener clutter, that is not easy to follow and that is not working on all occasions.

To resolve this issue I would like to implement a event bus with RxJava that hopefully reduces the complexity of my application.

---

**The problem:

Is it possible with RxJava to have a fallback observer for a observable, to react to events, if no other observer is available?**

E.g. All activities/fragments register themselves to get informed about certain events, so they can update the UI, if necessary.
When a activity/fragment is created/destroyed it automatically registers/unregisters itself from the event bus.

If the app is now in background, there should be no observers registered anymore. In that case only I would like to use a fallback observer that is handling those events.

I would like to achieve the following:
If in foreground: On event, update the UI.
If in background: On event, show toast / notification.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your app shouldn't show anything when it's in the background (user is not interested in it anymore, or is doing something else, so don't spam him with toasts (as he probably would not even know which application raised this toast)).

However,

You can solve this problem with `Subject`. Let say you have `MyServiceErrorHandler` class with `PublishSubject>` inside, so every time there is some part of UI is visible and capable of showing error is should be subscribed to this subject. Then you can expose method like `onError(Throwable t)` which will call `subject.hasObservers()`. If yes it pushes data to subject (so it will emit an event to currently subscribed UI) if no you can do some fallback thing (like displaying toast/notification/logging something/etc). This solution is however error prone to rotation as you may receive your result while screen is rotating (thus not subscribed yet)

You can extend this approach a little bit and use a `BehaviourSubject` which will replay it's last event for every subscriber (pretty handy in case of screen rotation). So you're posting event to this subject even though there are none subscribers, and when user opens this app back again (and one of your UI element will subscribe) it will receive last event with error (so you can show it properly). But in that solution you would need a little bit more logic to `clear` this subject in case of obsolete/already consumed errors (to prevent it from showing on every rotation/etc).